# Cannot start into Windows 7 Home Premium recovery

Tags: windows-7

I tried to start my recovery drive but I cannot.

I select the recovery option, I see Windows is starting.

As soon as the progress finishes, my computer reboots.

I can logon to my Windows without any problems. I just want to recover it to factory defaults.

Is there a way to fix the Recovery system?

Laptop info:
ASUS
Model: X42J
MB Ver: K42JY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use my ASUS-provided Windows 7 key with new installation?](http://superuser.com/questions/1077166/can-i-use-my-asus-provided-windows-7-key-with-new-installation)

Comment: Did you try the F9 key at boot to load the Asus factory recovery options?

Comment: @Moab Yes I did it. It boots into recovery but just before displaying dialog of available options. It reboots.

Comment: You may have a hard drive failing, I would clone the old drive to a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have submitted two questions, but they are not duplicate of each other. And they are not related, too.