# Can I use my ASUS-provided Windows 7 key with new installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image

I have a ASUS laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium key in the back.

My recovery cannot be started for some reason, I wish I can find solution for it.

So my only option is to install a new Windows 7 Home Premium from the legally provided ISO images in the Internet.

Can I use the key with these ISO images?

If I cannot what are my options? Asus website said they cannot provide a recovery ISO for me.

Comment: @Moab DigitalRiver

Comment: @Moab Yes there is a sticker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the COA sticker intact, use that Product key to reinstall W7.

The ISO you have must be one from Digital River so it will work with OEM Keys, other iso's from Microsoft only work with retail keys.

If you do not have a DR iso, you can use a Dell W7 disc to reinstall W7, it will install without entering a key, once at the desktop, [change the product key](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/genuine/product-key#T1=tab01) to the one you have on the sticker, then it should Activate.

Dell discs are plentiful, ask a friend, neighbor or co-worker to borrow one, that or search eBay for one, as they are cheap.